# Xcode 12 - GitHub Login Forced to use Personal Access Token

Tags: xcode

Xcode won't let me login to GitHub using my email and password, and is forcing me to use an account and personal access token. Of course, I could just generate a token and log in with that. However, I’d prefer not to have to use tokens - logging in with an email and password is just so much more simple.

Is this normal behavior, and is anyone else experiencing this? Maybe there is a workaround that I'm not aware of?

[image: Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts -> Add GitHub Account]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal behavior. GitHub is deprecating their basic auth with username/password for their API. In fact, when you access them via Xcode with an old account you get an email about it:

> Basic authentication using a password to the API is deprecated and
> will soon no longer work. Visit
> https://developer.github.com/changes/2020-02-14-deprecating-password-auth/
> for more information around suggested workarounds and removal dates.

Answer (score 1):

To do this, after you generate the token (recommend the repo token), go to xcode > Preferences > Accounts > GitHub

If SSH is shown: press Enter Password and a new screen appears with a placement for your token.  When you enter the token, the protocol will change to HTTPS.

That's it.

Comment: This is VERY well hidden in the UI! I tried making a new account but that fails if you're logged in, with a message that doesn't tell you why. Without this post I'd still be wondering...